# Query MySQL Database On-The-Go

Tags: mysql

I apologize if this question is elementary; I am new to Database administration.

I have a database on my home computer (iMac) that I would like to be able to access from anywhere (on any OS).  Specifically, I need to be able to query my data from any other computer.

How can I do this?

Comment: There are plenty of web based admin tools - [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) for MySQL (installed it once - seems OK and is widely used), a list of MS SQL Server tools can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4803534/470530) - not much of a SQL Server person!

Comment: @Vérace Thank you very much!  I just checked it out and it looks like the perfect solution.

Comment: @Vérace - Could you go ahead and post that as an answer, since it seemed to help the OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of web based admin tools - [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) for MySQL (installed it once - seems OK and is widely used).

The [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) tool is top-notch for administering MySQL - if you can telnet/ssh into your box, you can use it - I would recommend this approach as your starting point.

As a general tool, I also recommend [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) - a JDBC based tool - some shops can have strange requirements re. 3rd party tools and the like - worth looking at also!